# Valid placement-modifiers in locationURI for a menuContribution

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

The [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-09/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_menus.html) mentions `before`, `after` and `endof` as valid placement-modifiers in the locationURI of a `menuContribution`.

> ```
> <!ELEMENT menuContribution (menu* , command* , separator* , dynamic* ,> toolbar* , control*) >
> <!ATTLIST menuContribution
> locationURI CDATA #REQUIRED
> class       CDATA #IMPLIED
> allPopups   (true | false) "false">
> ```
>
> Defines an ordered set of additions to the command UI structure. The
>   defined elements will be added into the command UI structure at the
>   location specified by the locationURI element.
>
> This should be the starting point for all contributions into menus,
>   toolbars or trim, wherever they occur in the UI.
>
> - locationURI - A URI specification that defines the insertion point at which the contained additions will be added. The format for the URI
>     is comprised of three basic parts: Scheme: One of "menu", "popup" or
>     "toolbar. Indicates the type of the manager used to handle the
>     contributions Id: This is either the id of an existing menu, a view id
>     or the id of the editor 'type' Query: **The query format is <placement>=<id> 
>     where: <placement> is either "before", "after", or
>     "endof"** and <id> is the id of an existing menu item. The placement
>     modifier is executed when this contribution is processed. Following
>     contributions may change the final shape of the menu when they are
>     processed.
> - class - If this optional attribute is specified the provided class will be instantiated and used to provide menu contributions at this
>     location. If provided, all child elements will be ignored.
> - allPopups - By default popup contributions are not contributed to context menus that do not include an additions marker.

I've also seen `last` in some code snippet and tried it. It works. But "last" is not mentioned in the documentation. Knowing that the eclipse documentation is often outdated: How can I always see the valid options?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can find the only thing that looks at the placement value is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ContributionsAnalyzer`.

That accepts any value. It only actually tests for the `before` value, everything else is treated as `after`.